# 'find' files containing an integer in a specified range (in bash)

Tags: linux, bash, find

You'd think I could find an answer to this already somewhere, but I am struggling to do so. I want to find some log files with names like

```
myfile_3.log
```

however I only want to find the ones with numbers in a certain range. I tried things like this:

```
find <path> -name myfile_{0..67}.log #error: find: paths must precede expression
find <path> -name myfile_[0-67].log #only return 0-7, not 67
find <path> -name myfile_[0,67].log #only returns 0,6,7
find <path> -name myfile_*([0,67]).log # returns only 0,6,7,60,66,67,70,76,77
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: You cannot represent a range with a regular expression. Better use find to get files with a number and filter the output with another tool that perform the range checking, like awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to match an integer range using regular expression, use the option `-regex` in the your `find` command.

For example to match all files from 0 to 67, use this:

```
find <path> -regextype egrep -regex '.*file([0-5][0-9]|6[0-7])\.txt'
```

There are 2 parts in the regex:

- `[0-5][0-9]` matches the range 0-59
- `6[0-7]` matches the range 60-67

Note the option `-regextype egrep` to have extended regular expression.
Note also the option `-regex` matches the whole filename, including path, that's the reason of `.*` at the beginning of the regex.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I get the error "find: paths must precede expression"

Comment: ah yeah ok, but I still can't get the 'or' syntax to work. If I pick one half or the other it is fine, i.e. '.*default.log_[0-5][0-9]' (my files are named like default.log_56 etc.), but it doesn't match anything with the ( | ) syntax.

Comment: Ahh, it seems they all need to be escaped, i.e. `\( \| \)`.

Comment: and also damn, this doesn't match 0-9. So another part to the "or" is needed: `\([0-9]\|[0-5][0-9]\|6[0-7]\)`

Comment: I think also the extended regex is not needed for this, so `find <path> -regex '.*default.log_\([0-9]\|[0-5][0-9]\|6[0-7]\)'` works.

Comment: @BenFarmer If you add `--regextype egrep`, you need the escape character for the paraenthesis and or operators.

Comment: Some `find` implementations include a `-E` flag which instructs the regex parser to assume ERE rather than BRE.

Comment: @oliv, I'll just highlight that the `--regextype` long option appears to be exclusive to GNU find, and doesn't exist in other platforms (macOS, FreeBSD, etc).

Comment: @ghoti thanks for the remark. Seeing the tag of the question, I was assuming that OP was using GNU find...

Comment: @oliv, indeed, your answer certainly covers what's specified in the question, no argument there. I only mention it because I'm a stickler for portability. SO users come from all operating systems, and it can be frustrating to find an answer that *almost*  works. By including the BSDs you cover a large swath of the non-Linux world, though of course, Solaris' `find` doesn't even include `-regex`. :-P

Comment: And of course, from a score perspective, you can get a maximum of 25 points from the OP, but your score from future viewers of your answer may be limitless. :-)

Comment: The dot (`.`) before the trailing `txt` part in your regex matches any character (i.e. it has special meaning). It should be prefixed with backslash (`\\`) to match the literal dot character.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply and concisely, but admittedly not very efficiently, with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel find . -name "*file{}.txt" ::: {0..67}
```

In case, you are wondering why I say it is not that efficient, it is because it starts 68 parallel instances of `find` - each looking for a different number in the filename... but that may be ok.

Comment: Had a similar task, something which should take the PC a fraction of a second is taking it minutes and the fans are blowing, all processor cores are at 50%. Does at least seem to work but as you say, not that efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The following will find all files named `myfile_X.log` - whereby the `X` part is a digit ranging from 0-67.

```sh
find <path> -type f | grep -E "/myfile_([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]|6[0-7])\.log$"
```

**Explanation:**

- **`-type f`** finds files whose type is **f**ile.
- **`|`** pipes the filepath(s) to `grep` for filtering.
- **`grep -E "/myfile_([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]|6[0-7])\.log$"`** performs an extended (`-E`) regexp to find the last part of the path (i.e. the filename) which:

  - begins with `myfile_`
  - followed with a digit(s) ranging from 0-67.
  - ends with `.log`

---

#### Edit:

Alternatively, as suggested by [@ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) in the comments, you can utilize the `-regex` option in the `find` command instead of piping to `grep`. For example:

```sh
find -E <path> -type f -regex ".*/myfile_([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]|6[0-7])\.log$"
```

**Note:** The regexp is very similar to the previous `grep` example shown previously. However, it begins with `.*/` to match all parts of the filepath up to and including the final forward slash. For some reason, unknown to me, the `.*/` part is not necessary with `grep`<sup>1</sup>.

---

**<sub>Footnotes:</sub>**

<sup>1</sup><sub>If any readers know why the ERE utilized with find's `-regex` option requires the initial `.*` and the same ERE with `grep` does not - then please leave a comment. You'll make me sleep better at night ;)</sub>

---

Comment: Assuming the range can be represented as a regex, why would you [parse](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) the list rather than use find's `-regex` option?

Comment: Thanks @ghoti for the comment - good question! For some reason when I tried `find -E <path> -type f -regex "\/myfile_([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]|6[0-7])\.log$"` it didn't work.

Comment: @ghoti - I've since found that using find's  `-regex` option, (for reasons unknown to me), the expression needs to begin with `.*\/` to match the initial part of the full path before the filename. It wasn't necessary when piped to `grep`. Anyway, I've edited my answer to provide an example using the `-regex` option as per your suggestion. Thanks for the initial comment/nudge which prompted me to revisit the answer.

Comment: On my operating system (FreeBSD), `find`'s regex appears to be automatically anchored (i.e. if you specify a regex of `foo` it interprets it as `^foo$`). So the initial `.*` means "zero or more characters", and the string against which the regex is tested is the entire path, not just the filename. Also, I don't think you need to escape the forward slash, it has no special meaning in this context. So .. the equivalent to `find . -type f -name 'x*'` might be `find . -type f -regex '\.\(/[^/]*\)*/x[^/]*'`. This stuff is weird.

Comment: @ghoti - I agree regarding automatically anchored, however my ERE ends with `$` so I had assumed the initial `.*` ("zero or more characters") as unnecessary when utilizing find's `-regex` option - which clearly doesn't seem to be the case and that's what's baffling me. The initial `.*` was NOT necessary using the same ERE with `grep` (which was also testing the entire path). Yeah, agreed the escaped forward slash is unnecessary - have edited answer to omit that.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to build up the range from several ranges that can be matched by glob patterns.  For example:

```
find . -name 'myfile_[0-9].log' -o -name 'myfile_[1-5][0-9].log' -o -name 'myfile_6[0-7].log'
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot represent a general range with a regular expression, although you can craft a regex for a specific range. Better use find to get files with a number and filter the output with another tool that perform the range checking, like awk.

```
START=0
END=67
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    N=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/file_\([0-9]\+\).log/\1/')
    if [ "$N" -ge "$START" -a "$N" -le "$END" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done < <(find <path> -name "myfile_*.log" -print0)
```

In that script, you perform a `find` of all the files that have the desired pattern, then you loop through the found files and `sed` is used to capture the number in the filename. Finally, you compare that number with your range limits. If the comparisons succeed, the file is printed.

There are many other answers that give you a regex for the specific range in the example, but they are not general. Any of them allows for easy modification of the range involved.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The context was provided as a coment to the question, but you are right, it should had been here.